# Why does fgets continuousely return NULL?

Tags: c, fopen, fgets

I'm trying to write a program that can open all given files in a directory, and output the files with some changes to another directory given a path specified by the user. I made a function that will be called after `fork()` for each filename encountered in the current directory, and the output will have the same name in this new directory. I have looked all over, and I still can't find a reason as to why `fgets()` keeps returning `NULL`.

```
void sorter(char *fileName, char *directory, char*   newName){

    FILE *edit = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char buf[700];
    char *bufp = buf;
    char *fLine = fgets(bufp, sizeof(buf), edit);

    if (edit == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s\n", fLine);
    chdir(directory);
    FILE *output=fopen(newName, "w");   
    while(fLine){
        fprintf(output, fLine);
        fprintf(output, "done");    
    }   
    fclose(output);
    fclose(edit);
}
```

Comment: There are *a lot* of problems in this code, like a while loop controlled by the expression `fLine` that never changes in the loop.

Comment: does the file actually exist? in other words, what's the value of `edit`?

Comment: how about using [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) ??

Comment: @mangusta: I would expect a crash, not a null return, if `fopen` failed. I mildly suspect fake code too.

Comment: empty file maybe

Comment: this if statement "if (edit == NULL),,," should occur before the "fgets()" code.

Comment: @R.. I wouldn't expect anything for undefined behaviour :P

Comment: @M.M: I mean based on what common library implementations do, being that there's no reasonable transformation at the compiler level that would alter this.

Comment: Life is going to be interesting when this function returns but the current directory has been changed — affecting everything else in the program.  Be very leery of `chdir()`.  It's important, but it is 'dangerous' in that it can reset the expectations of everything else in the program.